# SAS drives not detected in JBOD's

Tags: sas, ubuntu-20.04, supermicro, jbod

I have two bnib Supermicro SYS-937R-E2JB JBOD connected with SFF8088 cables to my LSI 9200-8e HBA in my Dell T5810 workstation running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.  Neither the Seagate 12TB SAS or the Whitelabel 10TB SAS drives are recognized or detected.  When I do lsscsi the JBOD enclosure shows but not disks, I have ran lsiutil and there are no SAS discovery errors.  In lsiutil the enclosures show up with 6GB link active.  I have checked dmesg for errors and found nothing.  There is no activity lights on the HDD tray like they don't even have power.  Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Do you use interposer cards for the SATA drives as required by the enclosure?

Comment: figured out I didn't have the drives seated in the trays correctly, super noob mistake lol